# Using the notify.php with picture results in ".getId" error

Tags: php, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have this in my notify.php

```
   foreach ($request['userActions'] as $i => $user_action) {
        if ($user_action['type'] == 'SHARE') {
            write("SHARE");
            $timeline_item_id = $request['itemId'];

            $timeline_item = $mirror_service->timeline->get($timeline_item_id);

            foreach($timeline_item->getAttachments() as $j => $attachment) {
                write(json_encode($attachment));
              $attachment = $mirror_service->timeline_attachments->get($timeline_item_id, $attachment.getId());
              $bytes = download_attachment($timeline_item_id, $attachment);

              // Insert a new timeline card, with a copy of that photo attached
              $echo_timeline_item = new Google_TimelineItem();
              $echo_timeline_item->setText("Echoing your shared photo");
              $echo_timeline_item->setNotification(
                new google_NotificationConfig(array("level"=>"DEFAULT")));
              insert_timeline_item($mirror_service, $echo_timeline_item, "image/jpeg", $bytes);
              write("ECHO");
            }
            break;
        }
 }
```

The issue is that it says

```
       $attachment = $mirror_service->timeline_attachments->get($timeline_item_id, $attachment.getId());
```

that ".getId()" cannot be found.

I also have all the required files

```
require_once 'config.php';
require_once 'mirror-client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_MirrorService.php';
require_once 'util.php';
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$attachment.getId()` is not valid PHP. It should be

```
$attachment->getId();
```

with `.`, you're trying to concatenate the `$attachment` object with whatever the non-existent `getId()` function might return.

Comment: It's directly from the PHP-starter-example so I was so confused. Testing now.